# What is the biggest and smallest decimal number that can be stored using Django's DecimalField?

Tags: django, django-models, decimal

I could not really find anything in the doc. For the field, we need to provide two parameters: max_digits, and decimal_places.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

The above config stores upto 99999999.99. However, I was wondering if there is a maximum or minimum limit for this field, similar to how these constraints exist for other fields. For instance, IntegerField can store only from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

Comment: The source code does not specify constraints other than that the `max_digits` should be greater than 0, and `decimal_places` greater than or equal to 0, but the database itself can of course have restrictions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you have an idea of what those restrictions might be? I am trying to give my users the biggest range possible, so I would like to set my field in that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `IntegerField`

For the `IntegerField`, Django explicitly mentions the range as:

> **`class IntegerField(**options)`**
>
> An integer. **Values from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`** are safe in
> all databases supported by Django.

Even then that is not *per se* the limitation, but from then onwards, it is up to the database to support it. For example for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), it will take an `INT`, which results in a range of -2'147'483'648 to 2'147'483'647.

## `DecimalField`

If we take a look at the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DecimalField) we see that two checks are done:

> ```
> digits_errors = [
>     *self._check_decimal_places(),
>     *self._check_max_digits(), ]
> ```

If we look deeper into these checks, we only see that the `max_digits` should be larger than zero (so `> 0`), and the `decimal_places` larger than or equal to zero (so `>= 0`).

But that does *not* mean that the database will per se accept it. For example in the [MySQL specifications for a `DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html), we see:

> The declaration syntax for a `DECIMAL` column is `DECIMAL(M,D)`. The
> ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:
>
> - **`M`** is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a **range of 1 to 65**.
> - **`D`** is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of **0 to 30** and must be no larger than
>   `M`.

So even if Django accepts certain values, that does not mean every backend will accept these. These can also vary among the database backends. For example in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html), we have:

> up to **131072 digits before the decimal point**; up to **16383 digits after the decimal point**.

It is thus better to consult the documentation of the database backend. If you try to define the table, you will obtain an error in the migration, so you can simply "try" to use such large values, and see if the database can handle them.

That being said, 65 digits will probably be sufficient for most applications. The maximum value is larger than the square of [*Avogadro's constant* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), so unless you want to do arithmetic on numbers that are better expressed with [*Knuth's up-arrow notation* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) there are no problems.